# IOS Paper App UITableViewCells inertial animation

Tags: uitableview, animation, ios7, transition

I would like to  achieve same animation as Paper app. It looks like an **inertial** animation so when user push/pop a viewController the **visible cells** are moving horizontally in/out each one having a small delay from the one above.

Following a video showing the transition:

```
http://162.243.98.252/videos/PaperSettings/PaperSettings.hyperesources/PaperSettings.mov
```

thanks